# PHP Startup warnings when using Laravel

Tags: apache-http-server, php

Every time I run `php artisan serve` using bash, I get these PHP Warnings: `Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' / 'pdo_oci', the specified module could not be found in Unknown on line 0`.
The thing is that outside laravel, I can connect and query Oracle databases just fine using both `oci8_12c` (verified using `oci_connect(), oci_parse() and oci_execute()` functions) and `pdo_oci` (I built an oracle db wrapper using pdo and it works just fine) extensions.
Moreover, none of these php warnings are thrown when I launch apache (using xampp), I checked the errors.log and there are no problems.
Is there anything else I can check? Do you have any idea why on earth I get these messages when I try to use artisan?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I solved this situation, apparently the problem was that `msvcr120.dll` was missing, error thrown when I ran `php.exe`.
However, I still have no idea why I could connect to Oracle databases without errors being thrown, or, why I could use php at all, given the situation.